# openvpn sheathing with stunnel routing issues

Tags: routing, openvpn, stunnel

I'm trying to configure a new OpenVPN server running on Ubuntu (distro doesn't matter to me), but tunneled inside of stunnel (to avoid DPI).  My issue is if I have my client configured to route everything through the VPN, then I get zero traffic through.  The same configuration without stunnel works just fine.  My suspicion is there's some sort of localhost routing issue, and I just can't nail it down.

My OpenVPN server config:

[...]

```
topology subnet
port 1196
proto tcp
mode server
```

[...]

```
dev tun0
server 192.168.81.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bybass-dhcp"
push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.10.254"
```

My stunnel configuration on the same OpenVPN server:

```
# Connection
[openvpn-localhost]
# Incoming connection port
accept = 8443
# Connection to local OpenVPN server
connect = 127.0.0.1:1196
```

My main network is 192.168.10.0/24, and the VPN subnet is 192.168.81.0/24.  Also on the OpenVPN server, I have the following iptables rule to forward everything through:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
[...]

MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.81.0/24      anywhere
```

IP forwarding is also enabled in the kernel.

On my OpenVPN client, I'm connecting to a local port that then tunnels the OpenVPN traffic to the server.  The stunnel configuration on the client:

```
[openvpn-localhost]
client = yes

# Local openvpn connection
accept = 127.0.0.1:1196

# Remote tunnel
connect = <my remote target>:8443
```

Once everything is connected, this is the routing table on my client:

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.81.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0         0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0         0 wlp2s0
127.0.0.1       192.168.43.1    255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0         0 wlp2s0
192.168.10.0    192.168.81.1    255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp2s0
192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 wlp2s0
192.168.81.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
```

192.168.43.0/24 in this case is the tether I'm connected to in order to test this.  It is not connected to my internal network at all.

My client is unable to ping anything on the VPN.  Any help or input here to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

what you are required to is adding the following route push line to the openvpn config file (On the server side):

```
push "route [ENDPOINT_IP] 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"
```

OR

You can manually add that route (every time you want to use it - or you may add it to your network script) on the client by typing:

```
sudo route add -host (or -net) [DESTINATION-SERVER-IP aka ENDPOINT_IP] gw [YOUR-LAN-GW-IP] (e.g. 192.168.10.1) netmask 0.0.0.0 dev [Interface] (e.g. wlp2s0)
```

If this doesn't work;
Also you you might want to check if you have ip-v4.forwarding enabled in /etc/sysctl.conf file.

Best and good luck